# SHA1 Algorithm in FileInfor properties of .Net Project EXE

Tags: c#, .net, security, exe, sha

The metadata of the .Net EXE shows that it has been using SHA1 for its internal purpose.
The property navigation is : Metadata->Headers->FileInfo->SHA1

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create any console app with .Net Framework or.Net Core
2. Generate the EXE
3. Use any .Net Reflector to view Metadata. For Eg. [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/#section=web-installer)
4. Load the EXE and navigate to the above path - Metadata->Headers->FileInfo->SHA1
5. It shows SHA1 is key and has some value associated with it.

Screenshot of the same:[image: Metadata Properties]

Questions:
As it is known that SHA1 is not secure and SHA256 should be used everywhere.

1. What is this property about and where is it used internally?
2. Do we have the option to change it to SHA256 due to security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Docs: [PE Format#Certificate Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#certificate-data)

> A PE image hash (or file hash) is similar to a file checksum in that the hash algorithm produces a message digest that is related to the integrity of a file. However, a checksum is produced by a simple algorithm and **is used primarily to detect whether a block of memory on disk has gone bad** and the values stored there have become corrupted. A file hash is similar to a checksum in that it also detects file corruption. However, unlike most checksum algorithms, it is very difficult to modify a file without changing the file hash from its original unmodified value. A file hash can thus be used to detect intentional and even subtle modifications to a file, such as those introduced by viruses, hackers, or Trojan horse programs.

Emphasis mine.

Modifying (or recreating) an executable and making it have the same hash is still not trivial, not even for SHA-1. See also [Cryptography.SE: How secure is SHA1? What are the chances of a real exploit?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48289/how-secure-is-sha1-what-are-the-chances-of-a-real-exploit).

Comment: Wouldn't the .Net framework should consider this to upgrade or provision is available to us.

Comment: I'm sorry what?

Comment: I was asking if Microsoft would/should consider changing algo used in the above approach.